# Protect Core Data calls with NSOperationQueue addOperationWithBlock

Tags: iphone, core-data, concurrency

I have a process with several steps I need to perform and each one needs to be completed before the other (synchronous, serial, etc.). I want to use the idea of queues, and have one for my db updates to protect core data. What's the best way to fire off something to update/access core data, but ensure I can do what I need to serially once it's done? I've got the below, but how do i do something when it's done? Do i even need to bother with this to "protect" my core data or if the whole thing is serial, I can just access it?

```
        [databaseQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                        // access MOC to update DB
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to serialize your access, the new managed context architecture (private queue) could be used exactly for that.

you define a managed object context like so:

```
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
context.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;
//any other initialization you need
[ContextProvider setWorkerContext:context];
```

This context will operate on a background thread using GCD.

You need to retain this context (say in your app delegate, or any other place that make sense to you as long as you have access to it when you need to).

This context could now function as a queue for all operations you need (you might be able to accomplish what you need without NSOperations).

To issue a task to the queue you simply call:

```
[[ContextProvider workerContext] performBlock:^{//do something asynchronously
    //Do whatever you need to do
    //The context will serialize tasks in the order they were queued
    //You will probably want to save at the end of each task.
}];
```

You can add wrappers to call a completion block if you like, or listen to context change/save event.

You will want `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` if you need dependencies between your tasks, or you would like to be able to cancel your tasks (you will still need to check if the task was canceled) in a convenient manner, but then you will most likely want more than one context.

In any case, only one context can write to the store at any given moment (the store is serial when writing), other writing/reading context will be blocked from accessing the store during the write.